# Finding the first occurence of any of several strings in a `QByteArray`

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I have a `QByteArray` and a few strings. I'd like to find the first occurence of any of those strings, but there isn't a method for it.

At the moment I use a few `indexOf`, but this must be inefficent since I'd like to stop at the first occurrence.

The `QByteArray` has also binary data, so I presume I shouldn't convert it to `QString`, and `QByteArray` doesn't have `QRegExp`.

What I have ATM:

```
    int pos  = buffer.indexOf("$G");
    int pos2 = buffer.indexOf("XB00");
    pos = pos == -1? pos2 : std::min(pos, pos2);
    pos2 = buffer.indexOf("XA00");
    pos = pos == -1? pos2 : std::min(pos, pos2);

    buffer.remove(0,pos-1);
```

With `qt5`. `Qt`'s `indexOf` uses [qbytearraymatcher.cpp](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qbytearraymatcher.cpp) behind the scenes.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? indexOf() finds exactly the first occurrence of searched string...

Comment: I dont think it is efficient. If the buffer were big starting with `XA00` it would scan all of it twice. I guess I'll implement a `indexOf` that takes several strings myself.

Comment: Ah, maybe it isnt clear enough, the first occurence of *any* of the three strings. `IndexOf` only takes one string.

Comment: IndexOf take QString as argument, thats not enough?

Comment: Ahh first occurrence of any... now I understand